# Starting Android app with android studio errors: Fatal signal 13 SIGPIPE code -6

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a Android application and I'm testing the application on a galaxy s3 mini which runs on android 4.1.2 (api 16). Whenever I start the application with the standard run configuration, the app launches without any  problem but the phone gets very slow. When I look in the logcat i see the following error occuring like every 1-3 seconds :

```
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/goldenxx/golden:4.1.2/JZO54K/I8190XXAMG4:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): pid: 6506, tid: 6506, name: sh  >>> /system/bin/sh <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): signal 13 (SIGPIPE), code -6 (?), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     r0 ffffffe0  r1 40853100  r2 0000071e  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     r4 00000000  r5 00000003  r6 408530dc  r7 00000004
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     r8 40853100  r9 40853050  sl 40853100  fp 400c3cb8
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     ip 400c7f40  sp befa3640  lr 400b0501  pc 400d9958  cpsr 00000010
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d4  74732f62696c2f6d  d5  6d6f63786d6f5f65
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d6  2f73746e656e6f70  d7  726f646e65762f3a
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d16 c1c9a74918ba3d71  d17 3f50624dd2f1a9fc
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d18 41a19089a2000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     scr 00000010
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     #00  pc 0000c958  /system/lib/libc.so (write+12)
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     #01  pc 0000e4fd  /system/bin/mksh
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3600  0000100b  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3604  400e2387  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5178)
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3608  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa360c  00000004  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3610  408530b0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3614  400e2387  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5178)
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3618  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa361c  400c7eac  /system/bin/mksh
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3620  40853048  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3624  400cccc4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3628  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa362c  40853100  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3630  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3634  00000003  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3638  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa363c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     #00  befa3640  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3644  0000071e  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     #01  befa3648  40853048  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa364c  00013804  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3650  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3654  400c7eac  /system/bin/mksh
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3658  400ccd84  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa365c  400ccd88  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3660  400ccbb0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3664  40853048  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3668  4084ff9c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa366c  400ccdf6  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3670  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3674  400ad5cd  /system/bin/mksh
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3678  40853048  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa367c  0000001f  
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3680  408530cc  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):          befa3684  40852c5c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530e0 656e2f63 74782f74 6174715f 64697567  c/net/xt_qtaguid
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530f0 6174732f 00007374 00000000 0000100b  /stats..........
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853100 20786469 63616669 63612065 745f7463  idx iface acct_t
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853110 685f6761 75207865 745f6469 695f6761  ag_hex uid_tag_i
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853120 6320746e 735f746e 72207465 79625f78  nt cnt_set rx_by
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530bc 40116534 00000010 00000012 00000000  4e.@............
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530cc 00746163 00000000 0000002b 408530c8  cat.....+....0.@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530dc 6f72702f 656e2f63 74782f74 6174715f  /proc/net/xt_qta
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530ec 64697567 6174732f 00007374 00000000  guid/stats......
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530fc 0000100b 20786469 63616669 63612065  ....idx iface ac
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530e0 656e2f63 74782f74 6174715f 64697567  c/net/xt_qtaguid
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530f0 6174732f 00007374 00000000 0000100b  /stats..........
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853100 20786469 63616669 63612065 745f7463  idx iface acct_t
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853110 685f6761 75207865 745f6469 695f6761  ag_hex uid_tag_i
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853120 6320746e 735f746e 72207465 79625f78  nt cnt_set rx_by
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853030 00000000 00000004 00000000 0000001b  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853040 408530d8 00000000 408530cc 408530dc  .0.@.....0.@.0.@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853050 00000000 00000063 40853040 40852d18  ....c...@0.@.-.@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853060 befa3aec 00000000 00000000 4084f00c  .:.............@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853070 4085305c 40852b8c 00000006 00000003  \0.@.+.@........
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530e0 656e2f63 74782f74 6174715f 64697567  c/net/xt_qtaguid
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     408530f0 6174732f 00007374 00000000 0000100b  /stats..........
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853100 20786469 63616669 63612065 745f7463  idx iface acct_t
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853110 685f6761 75207865 745f6469 695f6761  ag_hex uid_tag_i
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     40853120 6320746e 735f746e 72207465 79625f78  nt cnt_set rx_by
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c3c98 27000a27 49005c00 22005346 27262423  '..'.\.IFS."#$&'
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c3ca8 3a2a2928 3e3d3c3b 605c5b3f 007d7c7b  ()*:;<=>?[\`{|}.
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c3cb8 203a7325 67007325 68626172 00747369  %s: %s.grabhist.
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c3cc8 20646162 74736968 2079726f 61727261  bad history arra
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c3cd8 20200079 25002020 64252073 20636600  y.    .%s %d.fc 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c7f20 400da0e4 400e683d 400ef9d1 400da4b8  ...@=h.@...@...@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c7f30 400d954c 400d9930 400db9e8 400e3e51  L..@0..@...@Q>.@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c7f40 400d994c 400e56d9 400d97f4 400e6769  L..@.V.@...@ig.@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c7f50 400da900 400e67a1 400daccc 400da0ac  ...@.g.@...@...@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400c7f60 400d97d8 400d97bc 400d95d8 400da2a0  ...@...@...@...@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     befa3620 40853048 400cccc4 00000000 40853100  H0.@...@.....1.@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     befa3630 00000000 00000003 df0027ad 00000000  .........'......
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     befa3640 00000000 0000071e 40853048 00013804  ........H0.@.8..
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     befa3650 00000001 400c7eac 400ccd84 400ccd88  .....~.@...@...@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     befa3660 400ccbb0 40853048 4084ff9c 400ccdf6  ...@H0.@...@...@
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400d9938 ef000000 e8bd0090 e1b00000 512fff1e  ............../Q
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400d9948 ea00b51e e92d0090 e3a07004 ef000000  ......-..p......
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400d9958 e8bd0090 e1b00000 512fff1e ea00b517  ........../Q....
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400d9968 e1a0c00d e92d00f0 e89c0070 e3a070b4  ......-.p....p..
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400d9978 ef000000 e8bd00f0 e1b00000 512fff1e  ............../Q
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400b04e0 f7f36800 4631ed6a 46584602 fe64f009  .h..j.1F.FXF..d.
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400b04f0 b320e025 200146c2 463a4651 ed80f7f3  %. ..F. QF:F....
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400b0500 bf1c1c43 0707ebc0 d1154482 ed1ef7f3  C........D......
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400b0510 2a046802 f7f3d010 6800ed1a ed4cf7f3  .h.*.......h..L.
I/DEBUG   ( 1667):     400b0520 44794916 48164602 f0094478 b17dfe45  .IyD.F.HxD..E.}.
I/BootReceiver( 2015): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
I/DEBUG   ( 1667): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 6506
I/dumpstate( 6695): begin
F/libc    ( 6729): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x00001a49 (code=0), thread 6729 (sh)
```

I'm using Android studio 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 15.04 with Oracle jdk 1.8.0_60. This problem also occurs on a simple application with just a edittext saying "helloworld", I don't think it's anything project related. It doesn't happen when I make a signed apk and install it with adb install.

ps: After I uninstall the application the error still comes up for 1-2 mins and then it stops.

ps2: I've tried different devices: Galaxy s6, galaxy s4 and a huawei one. On these phones I didn't have this problem.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this?

Comment: Seems to me like this could be a corrupted Android studio file. But this is only a first glimpse estimate. Voting up so this gets noticed earlier..

Comment: I have same problem on Samsung Galaxy Win (only on custom ROM) but on another my phones isn't this problem. I think that it specific problem for some ROMs or in AndroidStudio (maybe adb). Without debugger when I just run app it's work as well as need. P.S. Sorry, for my poor English.

Comment: On debug log I only can say that Dalvik has problem with memory allocation for execution of your app.

Comment: I had the same problem with Android 4.1.2(all devices) and Android Studio 1.4. Downgrading to 1.3 solved the issue

Comment: Same here.
I used only gradle (2.1.0 plus experimental:0.7.0) to build my app and "adb install" to run it.
Sony Xperia S, Android 4.1.2
Downgrading Android Studio is not solution for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downgraded android studio to 1.3 this solved the problem.

Comment: We had same problem with Android 4.1.2 and Android Studio 1.4

Answer (score 1):

I just added a filter in Android Studio to `Show only selected application`. This will filter out all logging except for the app you are working on. You can set filters in the right of the Android Monitor tab.